# Debo juntar 2 archivos PDF pero no se que valor retornar para que cumpla con el tipo de dato

Tags: c#

Tengo este codigo en C# y me dice que no tengo ningun dato sobre los PDFs que quiero unir.

```
public static string[] GetFiles()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Games");
    FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");
    int i = 0;
    string[] names = new string[files.Length];
    foreach (var r in files)
    {
        names[i] = r.FullName;
        i = i + 1;
    }
    // Cambio a:
    return names;
}
```

Comment: `return names`? No se si entiendo la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias no tenia claridad en este caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si usas

[Directory.GetFiles Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_)

este retorna un `string[]` por eso quedaria

```
public static string[] GetFiles()
{
    return Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Games", "*.pdf");
}
```